# Media query does not work in SCSS without !important

Tags: html, css, sass, media

There is the code of the `.modalBox` class

```
.modalBox {

  //modalBox styles
  &#{&} {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: $brand-dark;
    left: calc(50% - (#{$modalBox-width} / 2));
    top: calc(50% - (#{$modalBox-height / 2} + #{$modalBox-padding-bottom / 2}));
    width: $modalBox-width;
    height: $modalBox-height;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: $modalBox-padding-top $modalBox-padding-left-right $modalBox-padding-bottom;
  }

  //Inner main modalBox div
  &--inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0 em(50) em(25);
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

And the is the media query which I am trying to use

```
@media screen and (max-width: em(602)) {
  .modalBox {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

This query does not work without !important and I dont know what to do with it. If you have any suggestions, please, let me know

Comment: Try changing `&#{&}` to just `&`

Comment: @Blazemonger yeah, it works, thanks. But what is the difference between these two>

Comment: Look at your compiled code. Oddly enough, `.modalBox.modalBox` is more specific than just `.modalBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `&#{&}` to just `&`. Oddly enough, `.modalBox.modalBox` is more specific than just `.modalBox`